# Android Development - 2D map with birdseye view

Tags: android, graphics, view

I am looking at creating a 2D birdseye view of a map where the user is basically working their way through it.

Is there a way that I can create the whole map in 1 go and store it somewhere, then simply only display a certain section of that map during game play?
e.g map size =100 x 100 but user can only ever see 5x5 (which is zoomed-in to use up 70% of the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might use too much memory if you store the whole 100x100 map as a bitmap/texture in memory and only display a certain part. I think you'll be more happy if you divide it into chunks of e.g. 5x5 and cache these chunks (only those that are visible and drawn right now). When the user moves and gets to a new chunk, you just draw the 5x5 tiles on a bitmap/texture and cache it for as long as it's visible (and unchanged).

Comment: Great thanks for the advice florian h. However, as I am looking to develop an Android App, do you have any ideas as the best way to do this for the Android? Should i use the drawable section, I will be coding this project in Java.

Comment: What part exactly? First you'll have to decide if you want to use OpenGL or Canvas. If you're using canvas you could, as a very simple approach, just use a 2-dimensional array of Bitmaps which can store all the 5x5 chunks (or just those that are visible right now) and draw them to your canvas, depending on the player's position. For doing canvas-based games you should have a look at the demo projects in the SDK, there's something like that in there!

Comment: I intend on using a Canvas and the 2d array of bitmaps seems like the best way to go. I assume i will essentially have to use a massive if statement or something to work out whether the user has reached the end of the currently drawn canvas adn then simply draw the next section. Thank you for your help this should really aid my development.

Comment: You're welcome… it's a bit hard to explain, but if you have any further questions - just ask :)

Comment: I have been thinking about it and I indent on creating 1 big 2d array and the create a loop which is drawing the first 5 arrays to canvas (essetially will have N,E,S,W) then each time the player makes a move to draw the next set of arrays, therefore the screen will always show the up to date map. The map will look similar to a maze as for the actual gameplay. Does the above seem the best way to go about doing this. Thanks again